# Issue getting the MAC address of a HID device

Tags: c#, bluetooth, pinvoke, hid

I have a application that has bluetooth HID support, I'm getting an exception on one of my invokes:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DS4 Tool\DS4Windows\bin\Release\DS4Windows.vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'HidLibrary!HidLibrary.NativeMethods::HidD_GetSerialNumberString' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

The C++ Signature:

```
BOOLEAN __stdcall HidD_GetSerialNumberString(
  _In_   HANDLE HidDeviceObject,
  _Out_  PVOID Buffer,
  _In_   ULONG BufferLength
);
```

My signature:

```
[DllImport("hid.dll")]
static internal extern bool HidD_GetSerialNumberString(IntPtr HidDeviceObject, byte[] Buffer, ulong BufferLength);
```

My usage:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[126];
NativeMethods.HidD_GetSerialNumberString(safeReadHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), buffer, (ulong)buffer.Length);
string MACAddr = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", string.Empty).ToUpper();
MACAddr = String.Format("{0}{1}:{2}{3}:{4}{5}:{6}{7}:{8}{9}:{10}{11}",
  MACAddr[0], MACAddr[1], MACAddr[2], MACAddr[3], MACAddr[4],
  MACAddr[5], MACAddr[6], MACAddr[7], MACAddr[8],
  MACAddr[9], MACAddr[10], MACAddr[11]);
serial = MACAddr;
```

The odd thing is the method still returns a MAC address despite the error. Should I just ignore it? is there a better way to retrieve the MAC?

Comment: Umm... and what is the signature of the native C/C++ function? Most likely you use the wrong calling convention for your P/Invoke...

Comment: I've had trouble finding documentation on it, but i'm semi sure i'm using it correct.

Comment: @elgonzo found and added

Comment: should I be using IntPtr instead of byte[] maybe?

Comment: Wait... ULONG is a 32-bit value... so on the C# side you should use an uint...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *BufferLength* parameter of the C function is of type `ULONG`. *ULONG* is a **32-bit** data type (see [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)). On the other hand, *ulong* in C# is a 64-bit data type and thus does not match the unmanaged/native *ULONG*.

The 32-bit C# data type that corresponds to the unmanaged/native *ULONG* data type would be `uint`, hence your C# declaration of the function should look like:

```
[DllImport("hid.dll")]
static internal extern bool HidD_GetSerialNumberString(
    IntPtr HidDeviceObject,
    byte[] Buffer,
    uint BufferLength
);
```

(For future reference: The MSDN documentation provides a table showing [which C# data type should be used for which unmanaged/native data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120.aspx). Unfortunately, this table does not cover *all* unmanaged/native data types used in the WINAPI.)

Comment: Would this be processor independent? Or do I need to vary my dec based on architecture?

Comment: The ULONG/LONG datatype is a data type from the Windows WINAPI and is always a 32-bit data type, no matter if it is x86 or x64 code. This also applies to the C datatype *long*. However, on different (Non-Windows) OS's things can be different ([see here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os))

Comment: Followup question, some stacks return either null or "000000000000" (0'd mac), any idea why or how to work around this?

Comment: I am not quite sure if i understand your question correctly... In C/C++ `NULL` is just an abstraction, NULL is essentially the integral value 0. However, in C# `null` is not a number - it specifically denotes a reference to no object...

Comment: right, i mean i've had returns of either or. not saying that the 0's are null, just that its also done that. Seems to be primarily focused to Toshiba BT stacks causing this issue.

Comment: Did you solve the issue with the Toshiba BT stack somehow?